# Can the tail of a dead cow be used to bring the dead to life?

Tags: tafseer, quranic-events

[This verse of Quran](http://tanzil.net/#2:73) recommends using the tail of dead cow for bringing the dead to life. 
In this verse it is said:

> **like that** does Allah bring the dead to life.

The term "like that" (كَذَ‌ٰلِكَ) means that it can be repeated and is not specific to that case only.

According to this verse can now the tail of a dead cow be used for similar purpose?

The people who did this miracle were ordinary humans and not a prophet. Does this mean that it is possible that in the current era that such miracles happen?

Although this is a miracle but Islam does not say that such miracles cannot happen in current era. I.e. Islam does not say miracles are finished.

The stories of Quran are for us who are living in current time. And one lesson of this verse is that if God can do this at past can do this at current era to.

Is there any case in history of Islam that a dead return to life?

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find it anywhere suggesting that it was a tail.

The verse 2:73 states:

> فَقُلْنَا اضْرِبُوهُ بِبَعْضِهَا ۚ كَذَٰلِكَ يُحْيِي اللَّهُ
>   الْمَوْتَىٰ وَيُرِيكُمْ آيَاتِهِ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَعْقِلُونَ

in English:

> And We said: Smite him with some of it. Thus Allah bringeth the
>   dead to life and showeth you His portents so that ye may understand.

The answer is *no*.

To be more specific:

> The term *"like that" (كَذَ‌ٰلِكَ)* means that it can be repeated and
>   is not specific to that case only.

The term *"Thus"* *"كَذَ‌ٰلِكَ"* : does not mean that it can be repeated. It was annexed with the last part of the verse.

That it was a miracle to show Allah's ability to revive the dead,

It wasn't Islamic-medicine it was a miracle, and as you know miracles are specific for Allah's messengers and prophets. and no human can bring anyone to life no matter what he uses.

Answer (score 3):

This verse does not recommend anything, in this verse Allah is talking to the Mushrikeen and is telling them that Allah can bring the dead back to life, and was using this story of the past.

Furthermore with anyone with an Arabic dictionary and a fair amount of knowledge of Nahu will know that the word (كَذَ‌ٰلِكَ) in the verse dose not mean that it can be repeated or anything, rather it means that Allah brings back to life the dead like this (how he brought back to life the man that was killed).

I conclude with the end of the same verse:

> كَذَٰلِكَ يُحْيِي اللَّـهُ الْمَوْتَىٰ وَيُرِ‌يكُمْ آيَاتِهِ
>   لَعَلَّكُمْ تَعْقِلُونَ'
>
> Thus does Allah bring the dead to life, **and He shows you His signs
>   that you might *reason***

[Suratul Baqarah Ayah 73 (tanzil.net)](http://tanzil.net/#2:73)